# Converting GPRMC GPS data to decimal format in PHP

Tags: php, gps, latitude-longitude, type-conversion

Tracking devices have the data sent in the `$GPRMC` which is not what I use in my Code would be googling for a PHP converting method to decimal format no avail.

Just got the solution to this had to boil my head on the content of `$GPRMC`
sample format e.g `$GPRMC,001225,A,2832.1834,N,08101.0536,W,12,25,251211,1.2,E,A*03`

Where:

```
RMC   Recommended Minimum sentence C

123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC

A            Status A=active or V=Void.

4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N

01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E

022.4        Speed over the ground in knots

084.4        Track angle in degrees True

230394       Date - 23rd of March 1994

003.1,W      Magnetic Variation

*6A          The checksum data, always begins with *
```

And the code:

```
$gps = $_REQUEST['gps'];

if($gps){
$buffer = $gps;
if(substr($buffer, 0, 5)=='GPRMC'){

    $gprmc = explode(',',$buffer);
    $data1['lattitude_decimal'] = DMStoDEC($gprmc[3],'lattitude');
    $data2['longitude_decimal'] = DMStoDEC($gprmc[5],'longitude');

    $data = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q='.$data1['lattitude_decimal'].','.$data2['longitude_decimal'].'+(PHP Decoded)&iwloc=A';

    print_r($data);
    echo "\n\n";
}
 }
   function DMStoDEC($dms, $longlat){

if($longlat == 'lattitude'){
    $deg = substr($dms, 0, 2);
    $min = substr($dms, 2, 8);
    $sec = '';
}
if($longlat == 'longitude'){
    $deg = substr($dms, 0, 3);
    $min = substr($dms, 3, 8);
    $sec='';
}


return $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
  } 

  ?>
```

Hope this will help someone

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Converting of $GPRMC GPS location to decimal I will edit the question better then my words were limited I later got an answer

Answer (score 0):

That's the typical post request:

```
POST /RoyS/?acct=1234&dev=null&gprmc=$GPRMC,132201,A,3128.7540,N,14257.6714,W,000.0,000.0,290314,,*e HTTP/1.1" 200 33 "-" "-"
```

The line should be `$gps = $_REQUEST['gprmc'];`. Are you sure about this line?

`if(substr($buffer, 0, 5)=='GPRMC') {`

Shouldn't it be:

`if(substr($buffer, 1, 5)=='GPRMC') {`

?
and you definitely ignored NWSE letters!

Answer (score -2):

[formula acá](http://tohemu.blogspot.com/2013/11/convertir-latlong-gprmc-grados.html)

```
list($dato1, $dato2, $dato3, $lat, $dato5, $lon, $dato7, $velocidad, $dato9, $dato10, $dato11, $dato12) = explode(',', $input_gps);

$resultado_lat = $lat / 100;

list ($latitud_entero, $latitud_decimal) = explode('.', $resultado_lat);

$resultado_lat_minutos = $lat - ($latitud_entero * 100);

$resultado_lat_segundos = ($resultado_lat_minutos / 60);

$resultado_lat_final = $latitud_entero + $resultado_lat_segundos;

if ($dato5 == 'S'){
    $resultado_lat_final = $resultado_lat_final * -1;
}

$resultado_lon = $lon / 100;

list ($longitud_entero, $longitud_decimal) = explode('.', $resultado_lon);

$resultado_lon_minutos = $lon - ($longitud_entero * 100);

$resultado_lon_segundos = ($resultado_lon_minutos / 60);

$resultado_lon_final = $longitud_entero + $resultado_lon_segundos;

if ($dato7 == 'W'){
    $resultado_lon_final = $resultado_lon_final * -1;
}
```

Comment: Descriptions are helpful.